# Polymer firebase.. Authentication with password and email

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer-1.0, polymerfire, firebase-polymer

I have a function that logs in a user successfully.

```
_login: function() {
   var email = this.$.emailvalue.value;
   var password = this.$.passwordvalue.value;

   return this.$.authenticate.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function() {
      // Sign-in successful.
      //this._animateView(); **returns undefined**
    }, function(error) {
      // An error happened.
    //     // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message; 
        console.log(errorMessage);
        // this._animateErrorView(); **returns undefined**
    });

  },
```

What I want is to call a function `this._animateView();` when a user logs in successfully and `this._animateErrorView()` when there is an error.

If I try to do that It returns undefined.. How do I solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of `this` is different in the callback function.

You can fix this in many ways, but here are two.

## capture the value of this in another variable

You cannot prevent `this` from getting a new value, since that's simply how JavaScript closures work. But what you can do is define a different value with the *value* that you need. A idiomatic name for the variable is `self`, although I personally prefer something more descriptive:

```
_login: function() {
   var email = this.$.emailvalue.value;
   var password = this.$.passwordvalue.value;
   var self = this;    
   return this.$.authenticate.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function() {
        self._animateView();
    }, function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message; 
        console.log(errorMessage);
        self._animateErrorView();
    });
  }
```

## use fat arrow functions

ES6 defines a new way to declare functions with so-called *fat arrows*  (`=>`). Aside from being slightly less code, these ensure the value of `this` in the lambda/callback remains unchanged. So

```
_login: function() {
   var email = this.$.emailvalue.value;
   var password = this.$.passwordvalue.value;
   return this.$.authenticate.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
        this._animateView();
    }, (error) => {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message; 
        console.log(errorMessage);
        this._animateErrorView();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Frank van Puffelen answer, there is also another approach which is used by polymer dev team all over the place:

```
_login: function() {
   var email = this.$.emailvalue.value;
   var password = this.$.passwordvalue.value;

   return this.$.authenticate.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function() {
      // Sign-in successful.
      //this._animateView(); **returns undefined**
    }.bind(this), function(error) {
      // An error happened.
    //     // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message; 
        console.log(errorMessage);
        // this._animateErrorView(); **returns undefined**
    }.bind(this));

  },
```

so basically you add `.bind(this)` to every callback at the end.